# Pass 2d Array from c++ to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The question is above. I can create a 2d array in qml like this:

```
function create()
{
    var array= new Array(9);
    array[0]= new Array(
}
```

So how I can create such array in c++? I tried:

```
QVariant myArray= QVariant([4,5,6,7]);
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QVariantList` which could be passed to qml:

```
QVariantList list;
list.append(QVariantList{5, 5, 6, 7});
```

Comment: How can i access it from qml? I tried `console.log(list[0])`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnSmith The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QVariantList and JavaScript arrays. How do you expose it to qml?

Comment: I had another error. Now all works fine and thank you for your great help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `QVariant` cannot store arrays, so this lines won't compile at all:

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 2};
QVariant v = array;
```

or

```
QVariant x = {0, 1, 2};
```

or

```
QVariant x{0, 1, 2};
```

A [specific type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantList-typedef) exists, though, so you'd be better doing:

```
QVariantList myArray =
{
    QVariantList{4, 5, 6, 7},
    QVariantList{0, "one", true}
    //etc
};
```

and access items like:

```
int x = myArray[0].toList()[0].toInt();
bool y = myArray[1].toList()[2].toBool();
```

Comment: If i try the first example, the error message is `error: use of deleted function ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’`

Comment: Right. These are the negative examples (not compiling). The `QVariantList` example is ok.

Comment: And how can I convert an existing array into QVarianList?