# Display a 2d array and its values from a c++ file into a qml file

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qml

I have this c++ harcoded 9 x 9 2d array and I want to diplay it in a qml file. How can I do that?
Here is the cpp file:

```
#include "SudokuModel.h"

SudokuModel::SudokuModel(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    sudokuMatrix = {
        {5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
        {8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        {4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1},
        {7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6},
        {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9}
    };
}

int SudokuModel::getValue(int row, int col) const
{
    return sudokuMatrix[row][col];
}
```

Here is its header:

```
#ifndef SUDOKUMODEL_H
#define SUDOKUMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>

class SudokuModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SudokuModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE int getValue(int row, int col) const;

private:
    QList<QList<int>> sudokuMatrix;
};

#endif
```

And this is the qml file and in its window I want to display the matrix:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls 6.0

Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("New Game")
}
```

Comment: I would rather use some `QAbstractItemModel` for instance `QAbstractTableModel` or a custom implementation derived from `QAbstractItemModel` utilizing the index function with row and column parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass 2d Array from c++ to qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725828/pass-2d-array-from-c-to-qml)

Comment: @iam_peter How can I do that?

Comment: Start with reading this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference and then follow the links through the documentation. Here is an example of a custom tree model which is overkill for your use case, but it will get you started https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

Comment: @iam_peter what if I want to have a 2d array of text object declared in c++ can I use tree model and then pass it to qml via setContextProperty?

Comment: The tree model example was just a showcase how to create a custom `QAbstractModel`. You should not use a tree model in your case. You should create a custom two dimensional model that represents your sudoku data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solutions I've used in the past.

1. QVariant/QVariantList

For a low barrier of entry, marshal your entire model via a `QVariantList`. In this case, since you want two-dimension, it would be something like this:

```cpp
QVariant Sudoku::GetValues() const
{
    QVariantList matrix;
    for (int r = 0; r < m_rows; r++)
    {
        QVariantList row;
        for (int c = 0; c < m_cols; c++)
        {
            row.append(sudokuMatrix[r][c]);
        }
        matrix.append(row);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you have to transmit the entire matrix even if only 1 cell has changed. So, there is a performance issue, also, there is a potential UI/UX issue, since when used as a model, the UI/UX has to tear down the previous model before applying the new model, and, that may result in a flickering.

2. Consider marshaling a 1D list of cells:

```
public class SudokuCell : public QObject
{
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(int row MEMBER m_row NOTIFY rowChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(int col MEMBER m_col NOTIFY colChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(int value MEMBER m_value NOTIFY valueChanged);
signals:
    void rowChanged();
    void colChanged();
    void valueChanged();
protected:
    int m_row;
    int m_col;
    int m_value;
};
```

Then, you can deliver a list of these via `QVariantList` (similar to 1) or via `QQmlListProperty`. Doing so, you can make the list static but have it react to individual value changes on any cell. That will reduce the flicker dramatically, and, also, your can use such list with a variety of UI/UX components, most simplistically, a `Repeater` where `row` and `value` could be used to configure the 2D nature of your component graphically, even though C++ data structure is 1D.